# ModuleNotFoundError: No module named 'pycoin'

Tags: python, module, pip

Code:

```py
from pycoin.ecdsa.secp256k1 import secp256k1_generator
```

When I run this, I get the error:

> ModuleNotFoundError: No module named 'pycoin'

I've tried doing:

> pip3 install pycoin

aswell as

> pip install pycoin

Both of which have lead to the same error.
I've ran the code on python and python3 which also leads to the same error.

Any solutions?

Comment: What environment are you running? Win/linux, venv, conda, Docker?

Comment: Manjaro Linux, although I'm not sure how this is related.

Comment: Like the answer below, this usually happens when you pip install into 1 python env, but try to import in another.

Comment: What environment should I use?

Comment: If you use default python on linux, you have `pip3` for `python3` and `pip` for `python` (version 2, if it is still installed). You should definitely look into venv for development and leave system python installation alone. For example https://realpython.com/python-virtual-environments-a-primer/

Comment: Do I have to use a different environment? This exact code and environment worked on Arch Linux before, so I don't think the environment I'm using matters.

Comment: Inside IDE print the output of `sys.path` and then search for `pycoin` in any of the folders specified in `sys.path`.

Comment: I've done so, I can't find pycoin in the folder.

Comment: So that's your problem, you installed it for some other python. You need to find out which python executable your IDE is using and then run `<full path to python exe>/python -m pip install pycoin`

Answer (score 0):

Go to terminal or cmd on windows and type `python3` (python2, python for older versions)
Then try to import the module there.
If the module in imported successfully then reopen your IDE. and then try.

Comment: It doesn't give an error when I import it in the terminal. I've reopened my IDE and it has the same error.

Comment: What IDE are you using? Is there a method of managing libraries from within there?